# Scalar multiplication of Subgroup of GF(p^n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have encountered this statement.

Consider the finite field $GF(p^n)$ where $p$ is a prime and $GF(p)$ is the base field.
Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GF(p^n)$.
Fix an arbitrary $x \in G$.
Then, $a \cdot x \in G$ holds for every $a \in GF(p)$.

I have two questions.

1. Why is this statement true?
2. What special properties does subgroup of $GF(p^n)$ has?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Use the following result:

> As a group under addition, $GF(p^n)$ is isomorphic to $$\underbrace{F_p \oplus F_p \oplus \cdots\oplus F_p}_{n \text{ times}}.$$

You can also visualize $GF(p^n)$ as a vector space over $F.$

Essentially what you are asking in 1) is just the scalar multiplication as in vector spaces.

2. For each divisor $m$ of $n,$ $GF(p^n)$ has a unique subfield of order $p^m.$
   Moreover, these are the only subfields of $GF( p^n).$

Comment: That is a great intuition! Thank you!

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.